# Adobe Flash Professional CC publishing to iDevice and receiving Installation Error: ApplicationVerificationFailed

Tags: ios, flash, air, adobe, creative-cloud

I'm using Adobe CC and am trying to make an app for iOS using Adobe Air. I have the app created and the .swf works but when trying to publish to my iPhone, I get the following error.

[image]

I have tried to use the answers from similar questions and the solutions are not working for me. I have revoked all certificates and permissions from the developer console and my KeyChain Access and starting again but I still receive the same error. I tried renaming the app in the App ID field in the Deployment Field but nothing seems to be working, any advice / solutions?

Also, if I unclick the Post Publishing checkbox which will push the app onto my device, I receive no error but when using iTunes to install the app, I get a message displaying "installing" but goes on indefinitely.

Comment: I can't tell you what it is but I think I can tell you what it's not.  It's not your device list.  When an ipad runs an app and isn't on the device list the app just does a quick blackscreen close usually.  I get your error randomly.  I just republish and it's gone.  But not being able to run the ipa by hand doesn't You should post your code and xml.  Is your version of AIR updated?

Comment: My Air is updated, one of the first things I checked. My first attempt I got the app on my iPhone but it just said installing and that was that. When I went back to the xml and tried to republish I got the above error. I can post the code but I don't think thats the issue.

Comment: You're trying to publish an empty app, right?  "Hello world"?  Still have to guess cause you don't post code.  If you're using CC and have AIR up to date, you should get something on screen.  you should go through your certificates again.  Make sure everything looks good in devloper.apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the advice, I found the error. It was to do with xCode, I just reinstalled it and now it works without any hiccups.